# DataGrid mostrar valor chave estrangeira ao invés do ID

Tags: c#

Estou mostrando os dados de uma tabela(`TB_LIBERACAO`) em um `DataGrid`, porem essa tabela tem 2 chaves estrangeiras vindas da tabelas `TB_CARROS` e `TB_MOTORISTAS`

```
TB_LIBERACAO
idLib
idCarro(FK)
idMotorista(FK)

TB_CARRO
idCarro
placa

TB_MOTORISTAS
idMotorista
nome
```

Nos campos `idCarro` e `idMotorista` ira aparecer os id's(numeros), porem gostaria que aparecesse o valor dos campos placa(`tbCarro`) e nome(`tbMotorista`).

Consigo fazer no banco de dados, porem não estou conseguindo passar para o C#

```
public void atualizarGrid() {
     LiberacoesControle liberacoesControle = new 
     LiberacoesControle();

     dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
     dataGridView1.DataSource = liberacoesDAL.preencherGrid();

            dataGridView1.Update();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
 }
```

Tenho um método que joga os objetos para uma lista e retorna essa lista

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource = liberacoesDAL.preencherGrid();)
```

---

```
public List<LiberacoesModelo> preencherGrid()
    {
        LiberacoesModelo liberacao = null;
        MySqlCommand comandoSql = null;

        try
        {
            abrirConexao();

            List<LiberacoesModelo> listaLiberacao = new List<LiberacoesModelo>();

            String sql = "Select * from liberacoes";
            comandoSql = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexao);

            comandoSql.Parameters.Clear();
            //comandoSql.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.String).Value = id;

            MySqlDataReader dr = comandoSql.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                liberacao = new LiberacoesModelo();

                liberacao.idliberacoes = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("idLiberacao"));
                liberacao.idcarro = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("idCarro"));
                liberacao.idmotorista = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("idMotorista"));
                liberacao.dataLiberacoes = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("dataLiberacao"));                    
                listaLiberacao.Add(liberacao);
            }
            dr.Close();
            return listaLiberacao;
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw erro;
        }
        finally
        {
            fecharConexao();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo na sua string sql coloque :

```
Select * from TB_LIBERACAO L
join TB_CARRO C on C.idCarro = L.idCarro
join TB_MOTORISTAS M on M.idMotorista = L.idMotorista
```

e no seu while que popula o DataSource coloque:

```
while (dr.Read())
        {
            liberacao = new LiberacoesModelo();

            liberacao.idliberacoes = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("L.idLiberacao"));
            liberacao.placacarro = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("C.placa"));
            liberacao.idmotorista = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("M.nome"));
            liberacao.dataLiberacoes = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("L.dataLiberacao"));                    
            listaLiberacao.Add(liberacao);
        }
```

Não sei se os campos e os nomes das tabelas estão corretos, mas o mais importante é o seu sql que vai retornar os valores que você está atrás.

Espero ter ajudado amigo.

Comment: Muito obrigado Maycon, tive que fazer uma mudança no código, mas você resolveu 99,9% do problema, vou postar abaixo as mudanças:

Comment: Massa, feliz por ter ajudado, qualquer coisa só falar ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal segue o método que funcionou pra mim aqui:

```
    public List<LiberacoesModelo> preencherGrid()
    {
        LiberacoesModelo liberacao = null;
        MySqlCommand comandoSql = null;

        try
        {
            abrirConexao();

            List<LiberacoesModelo> listaLiberacao = new List<LiberacoesModelo>();

            String sql = "Select * from liberacoes L join carros C on C.idCarro = L.idCarro join motoristas M on M.idMotorista = L.idMotorista";
            comandoSql = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexao);

            comandoSql.Parameters.Clear();
            //comandoSql.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.String).Value = id;

            MySqlDataReader dr = comandoSql.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                liberacao = new LiberacoesModelo();

                liberacao.idliberacoes = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("idLiberacao"));
                liberacao.placaCarro = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("placa"));
                liberacao.nomeMotorista = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("nome"));
                liberacao.dataLiberacoes = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("dataLiberacao"));                    
                listaLiberacao.Add(liberacao);
            }
            dr.Close();
            return listaLiberacao;
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw erro;
        }
        finally
        {
            fecharConexao();
        }
    }
```

Mudanças que fiz:

```
Maycon
liberacao.placacarro = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("C.placa"));
liberacao.idmotorista = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("M.nome"));

Alterado para: 
liberacao.placacarro = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("placa"));
liberacao.idmotorista = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("nome"));
```

Tive que adicionar mais dois geters/seter que retornavam string ao invés de int na classe LiberacoesModel,

```
public string placaCarro { get; set; }
public string nomeMotorista{ get; set; }
```